# Birkhoff polytope vs permutation polyhedron

Tags: permutations, polytopes, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

I cannot understand a few things about the [Birkhoff polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_polytope).
The Birkhoff polytope is defined as a polyhedron of all $n \times n$ [doubly stochastic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix). How is is it polytope then? To transform  $n \times n$ matrix into a point in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, we should multiply it by a  fixed vector or something? I couldnt find any explanaitions about how it does work. Also, does someone have full proof of the fact that in Birkhoff polytope  extreme points (vertices) are exactly [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)?

I can't also fully understand the difference beetwen Birkhoff polytope and permutation polyhedron ([permutohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron)). The second one is defined as convex hull of all permutations of fixed point, at it is deeply connected to Birkhoff polytope but I don't quite see the difference, aren't these exactly the same thing?

Comment: The following sentence from the Wikipedia article on [permutohedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron) suggests that the terminology may not be consistent across the literature: "Permutohedra are sometimes called permutation polytopes, but this terminology is also used for the related Birkhoff polytope, defined as the convex hull of permutation matrices." So whether these objects are different polytopes may depend on the author.

Comment: That being kept in mind, the slides [here](https://staff.math.su.se/nill/daten/kolkom.pdf) suggest that permutation polytopes correspond to permutation subgroups, whereas Birkhoff polytopes correspond to an entire symmetric group.

Comment: The Birkhoff polytope lives in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The map that sends an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ to $M v$ for some fixed $n \times 1$ vector $v$ is a projection from the Birkhoff polytope onto the permutohedron, but this is far from making them the same.  (Analogy: regular tetrahedra and squares both have four vertices, and there is a simple way to project a regular tetrahedron onto a square, but squares are not the same thing as tetrahedra.)